# c# if statement for macro

Tags: c#, if-statement, macros, shortcut

i am trying to create a macro with jitbit macro recorder, what i need is if statement for shortcuts, like "ctrl+y",  but software doesnt have if statement for shourtcuts. But there is Run "C# code" feature. I am trying to create a code for this. but failed so far.Can anyone help me?

Note: code must contain a class named Program with the static method Main.

Here is example code from the macro recorder;

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("test");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "if statement for shortcuts".

Comment: are you looking for [Snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7d3wz0k%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)?

Comment: Do you mean you want to execute code if the user presses a shortcut key (like ctrl+y)

Comment: yes exactly. for example if ctrl+y pressed do someting if ctrl+z pressed do another thing etc. but the code must contain class named Program and static method main.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are searching for:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo keyinfo;
        do
        {
            keyinfo = Console.ReadKey(true);

            if (keyinfo.Modifiers == ConsoleModifiers.Control)
            {
                if (keyinfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Y)
                {
                    // Do something
                }
                else if (keyinfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Z)
                {
                    // Do something else
                }
            }
        }
        while (keyinfo.Key != ConsoleKey.X); // Ends the program if you press X
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't use `keyinfo.Modifiers.ToString() == "Control"`, but `keyinfo.Modifiers == ConsoleModifiers.Control`

Comment: thx guys but software is giving error "check the code". If i delete string[] args  it accepts the code. But its not working, i guess i have to find another software. thx anyway.